# where to use "and" in listings

Tags: meaning, usage

> A more distributed global balance of power will create new
> opportunities for Israel, including links with Arab neighbours ***and
> with China and India***, which care little about the Palestinians.

Which is more common,for listing countries:

> links with Arab neighbours,China and India

or

> links with Arab neighbors **and with** China and India"?

There are two many "and"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the extra "and" here is intentional, and separates two different groups and reduces ambiguity.

The most common way to construct a list of similar items (which I think you already know) is

> I had dinner with **Alice, Bob, and Carol**.

But in this case, we have a [nonrestrictive clause](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/clauses) beginning with *which*, that gives more information: "which care little about the Palestinians."

If we just stick the which-clause at the end of the list, it looks like it applies to the entire list:

> I had dinner with Alice, Bob, and Carol, **who are tennis players**.

That makes it look like all of them are tennis players.

In this case, "Arab neighbors" definitely care about the Palestinians!  It is only China and India which don't care about the Palestinians.  So we really have two lists:

- Arab neighbors
- China and India

So we have to say what you saw:

> with (Arab neighbors) and with (China and India, which care little about the Palestinians).

Answer (score 0):

To make that specific sentence read more naturally, I’d reverse the order. “A more distributed global balance of power will create new opportunities for Israel including links with China and India, which care little about the Palestinians, and with Arab neighbours.